# Allow the Functions access only via APIM

Tags: azure-functions, azure-api-management

Our partner used to access our functions directly, recently we created an APIM and connected our Azure functions with it, and we use some method like JWT to secure it. But we found the partners still can access the functions as usual.
Is that possible to decline the access to functions from internet but APIM.

Comment: what are the authentication level of azure functions currently ,  if you set by function-specific keys,  why would partners could access ?

Comment: @Turbot Current access level is using app key, and the key already shared to partners.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to restrict access to your Azure functions:

1. Enable the [Private Endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint) feature. This will disable all public access and access will be restricted from within the VNET only. This feature will require an unused subnet, which will then be used to allocate an inbound private IP Address. Preferable to create a subnet within the same VNET as the APIM
2. Use [Access Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) feature and allow access to the subnet, which is used by APIM.

> NOTE: Other threads mentioned Regional VNet Integration which isn't correct as that feature is meant for making Outbound Connections. If your App Service needs to make a call to resource hosted within the VNet, then Regional VNet Integration is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> This is only sum up of discussion before. I try to sort answer because
> general title of question is magnifying search engin e.g. Google to
> this topic.

To restrict access only by APIM you need to change Azure Function authorization level from ANONYMOUS to function-key.
For example in Java this is about:

`@HttpTrigger(name = "request", methods = {HttpMethod.GET}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.FUNCTION)`

Link to documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.authorizationlevel?view=azure-java-stable

In case when you already share a function-key with some client which you would like to restrict you have two options:

- regenerate key and resend to proper client
- ip restriction

Answer (score -1):

You can try to put the function app and the APIM in a azure VNET, then internet access will be denied.

Have a look of this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

Comment: The function is already inside an VNet, and the function and storage is inside same subnet, otherwise it can't access the storage.

Comment: @William Have you already done this? I think this should be a good way to avoid external access.

Comment: @William If you use a trigger that does not require Storage, such as httptrigger, then you should not need to put Storage into the VNET.

Comment: @William And as Turbo said in the comments, if you are httptrigger, you can set the function access level so that only those with the key can access the function.

Comment: The VNet access only available for the service like storage, cosmosdb and VM, the app service not suitable for that.

Comment: @William If you don't want the partners to access function directly, you can delete the original key and create a new one.

Comment: you should consider revoking the keys for partner to access, since you would like to promote apim of use, you can do that gradually of revoking and start moving to apim use instead of direct use of azure functions.

Comment: Enabling VNET Integration doesn't block inbound access. VNet Integration is meant for outbound connections